# Does any one know what is the P value when F=37.45; df1=5; df2=40 in a one way anova F test?

Tags: distributions, probability

in a one way anova F test
when F=37.45; df1=5; df2=40
what is the P value?
I tried several software, and the result is <0.0001. I know it sounds weird that I need a really small number of possibility. However, I really need it for a publication.
I greatly appreciate if anyone can help on this issue. Please let me know the exact number if you can calculate it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0.00000000000004551914400963141815737
```

Is that exact enough?

Seriously, even though in a publication it asks for an exact amount there's a point where just saying it's less than 0.0001 is all you can reasonably do.  It's a very very very small number.  I strongly suggest that you not try to send that number in for publication and you stick with p < 0.0001.